# Want to start unity, need some basic idea of how to unity-fy some of my class ideas

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, behavior-tree

[This is a repository of mine](https://github.com/gioragutt/training/tree/master/ModuloZero/ModuloFramework/AbilitySystem), specifically the skill-system classes. I'm mostly doing work in XNA, which these classes work fairly well with.

These classes aren't finished, they're concepts for improving a previous game of mine, following some instructions from a [previous post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/51597/what-is-the-best-design-pattern-to-apply-effects-and-abilities).

I know about Unity's ESC(entity component system) approach, and I know the basics of what GameObject is and how components work, sorta.

The classes I've wrote manage stuff like effects on units, and how they are applied.

The flow is: `Behavior` -> `Effect` -> `Ability`

For example, `IBehavior` is the interface for behaviors.

I have several abstract classed:
`ActivatableBehavior` which is an abstract for all single proc behaviors
`TogglableBehavior` is base for, obviously, togglable behaviors
`LimitedTimeBehavior` is base for timed behaviors
Likewise, I have `DurationBehavior` and `TickBasedBehavior` which derive from `LimitedTimeBehavior`.

How would something like this be implemented in Unity?

If it helps, my game is supposed to be rather simplish, `Little Fighter 2` style, server-client based and so on...

If this Question is too broad and/or not clear enough, say what's missing and I'll try to add it!

Answer (score 2):

Just because Unity *has* an Entity-Component system doesn't mean you have to *use* it.  You could just as easily attach a single script to the main camera and do everything inside that script, treating it as your main game loop (I've worked on a project like this).

I don't really encourage the creation of `Components` which describe a tiny piece of behavior for a GameObject and interact back and forth with other `Components`.  e.g. all of your IBehavior objects would be used exactly as you're already using them: only called and stored within your Entity class.  Making them `Components` in their own right means attaching and removing them from GameObjects at runtime, which isn't the most efficient of procedures (removing one uses Unity's `Destroy()` method and sends the component to be garbage collected, which Unity is Not Very Good At).

The ECS Unity has is much better at a broader level, implementing the world and the actors within it, leaving the behavior pattern to a subsystem managed within those GameObject's attached scripts.  There are benefits to splitting one behavior into two, as exemplified by the default character controllers.  One script which simply moves the character around and a second script which tells the first which direction to move *in.*  That way, the same motor can be used by both AI units and the player just by swapping out the input script.  But having a separate script to handle every kind of input ("this script handles [E], that one [space]" etc.) and sub-behavior ("this script, when attached, causes the unit to search around for the player, that one makes them attack" etc.) is unnecessary.

You'll find various AI systems on the asset store that work like this: two or three scripts attached to a GameObject which then have their own internal ECS to manage the AI state machine or behavior tree (typically the AI state machine, the character motor, and a pathfind navigator) where every AI state and action is a script, but *not* one that inherits from `Component` (e.g. `MonoBehaviour`).